¿Como desactivar el scroll vertical de un DIV?
Como desactivar el scroll vertical de un div que esta por encima con una capa superior z-index:999, esto es para que el usuario vea primero el contenido y no haga scroll y no vea lo que esta abajo y al dar  clic al botón desaparezca ese div, esa función ya la tengo con translate  , con el estilo  overflow-y: hidden no funciona.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



  .texto {
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  
  #seccion1{
   background: #8c86e9;
     z-index: 999;
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilo.css" />
</head>
<body>


    <section id="seccion1">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="texto">
          <button>Ingresar</button>
          <p>Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
¿Por qué lo usamos?

Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).

        </p>
         </div>


       </div>
    </section>

    <section id="seccion2">
        <div class="container">
         <p>Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
 
             Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
             ¿Por qué lo usamos?
             
             Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
             Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
 
             Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
             ¿Por qué lo usamos?
             
             Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
             Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
 
 Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
 ¿Por qué lo usamos?
 
 Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
 
         </p>
 
        </div>
 
 
     </section>
    

</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/audio.js"></script>
</html>




¿Intentaste aplicar una altura mínima al div? ¿Y colocar overflow-y: hidden al container de ese texto?

Hola Miguel, para que haya scroll es necesario que el contenido ocupe más espacio que el que el contenedor ofrece. En tu caso el elemento con la clase texto no tiene un alto definido, por lo que no genera scroll. El que sí genera scroll es el body el cual sobrepasa el alto del viewport.

Una posible solución al problema que mencionaste es establecer un alto al elemento contenedor del texto (en este caso el que contiene la clase texto) para que te permita scrollear por este si se excede la altura establecida.
Por lo que te recomiendo simplemente:
.texto {
    padding: 20px; /* Le añadí un padding para que se visualice un poco más prolijo el contenido. */
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

Como bien dijo Mateo y queda claro en la documentación referenciada, es vital que un elemento HTML tenga establecido un alto ya que lo que maneja la propiedad overflow es cómo se muestra el contenido desbordado. En el ejemplo que dio @Miguel al no establecer un alto al div al que le quería ocultar el desbordamiento vertical, no hay desbordamiento que ocultar debido a que el contenedor se ajusta al contenido que se muestra en su totalidad.
Otras soluciones posibles son con JavaScript modificando el estilo desde allí, o bien, siguiendo lo mencionado por og.lopar711, podés utilizar la propiedad position: fixed adecuando las dimensiones a tus necesidades, para que el div sea lo que el usuario vea independientemente de si hace o no scroll y que desaparezca en tiempo y efecto que quieras.

No es una posible solución, es la solución ideal. De hecho, en la documentación menciona que para obtener el efecto deseado el contenedor debe tener un alto y/o ancho definidos.  Tómate la libertad de completar tu respuesta explicando ese punto

Haz (de nuevo) el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Lo primero que se menciona es que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, no es un foro; además, las menciones no funcionan en las respuestas. Si quieres mencionar a un usuario, comenta en la respuesta en la que también ha comentado (o si quieres responder al autor de una respuesta, hazlo como comentario en ella). Por cierto, soy padaleiana :)

Usa este fragmento de código:
window.addEventListener('scroll', (evt) => {
window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
}, true);

Explicación, cuando se detecte que se está haciendo scroll regresamos la posición de la ventana para que siempre sea (0,0) usando el método scroll(); el evento scroll detecta el wheel del mouse, las flechas del teclado y la barra lateral del navegador.
Y para detectar el scroll en un dispositivo con pantalla touch se puede utilizar el evento "touchmove" seteandolo como pasivo y usando preventDefault() para evitar que se pueda scrollear, así:
window.addEventListener('touchmove', (evt) => {
evt.preventDefault();
}, { passive :  false });

Con los ajustes el código completo es este:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css" />
    <script>
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', (evt) => {
    window.scroll({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: "smooth",
          });
    }, true);
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }, { passive :  false });
    
    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <section id="seccion1">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="texto">
          <button>Ingresar</button>
          <p>Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
¿Por qué lo usamos?

Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).

        </p>
         </div>


       </div>
    </section>

    <section id="seccion2">
        <div class="container">
         <p>Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
 
             Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
             ¿Por qué lo usamos?
             
             Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
             Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
 
             Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
             ¿Por qué lo usamos?
             
             Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
             Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
 
 Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
 ¿Por qué lo usamos?
 
 Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
 
         </p>
 
        </div>
 
 
     </section>
    

</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>




El fragmento del código es funcional, pero en mi caso es que solo lo quiero para un div  ya que lo tengo como principal con una capa superior o por encima a los demás secciones y lo que quiero es que el usuario no se brinque ese contenido haciendo scroll o deslizando hacia arriba.

@Miguel ahora entiendo mejor tu pregunta, siendo así, creo que puedes tener 2 opciones: 1, como te dice Fernando Pereyra en su respuesta define el alto del div y oculta el overflow. 2, Prueba usando position: fixed; para que aunque se haga scroll tu div también se movera con el viewport, ya despues que lo cierres regesas el div con position:initial o quizas también  puedes decidir hasta qué punto sigue scrolleando con el viewport, puesdes detenerlo en algún punto arbitrario, por ejemplo cuando ha escrolleado X cantidad de pixeles en Y
